# Edit specific cell on a DataGridView after binding

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

I have a DataGridView that is populated by a DataTable.
In the DataGridView manually I added two fields (CheckBox and TextBox).

After the data appear in the DataGridView, I can not edit the TextBox or CheckBox that I added manually.

The goal is to edit these fields, in order to do an Update which I will store these edited data.

Can you help?

The code to bind the DataGridView is:

```
        string strSQL = "select Domicilios.id_domicilio as [N.Domicilio], Utentes.nome as Nome from Domicilios inner join Utentes on Utentes.id_utente = Domicilios.id_utente WHERE (dbo.Domicilios.data_domicilio BETWEEN '" + dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "' and '" + dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") + "') and (estado <> 'Entregue') and (estado <> 'Anulado')";

        connection.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, connection);
        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        dataAdapter.Fill(table);
        bindingSource1.DataSource = table;

        dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;

        connection.Close();
```

And here is a print of the form, where the two firsts fields was where i can't edit:

[image]

Comment: You've made the DataGridView control readonly. That's why you wouldn't be unable to modify any columns.